# NDSolve dealing with message infinite expression and non numerical value non homogeneous differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages, singularity

I'm trying to solve the following differential equation with some specific conditions

```
NDSolve[{2 V[X] - 2 X Derivative[1][V][X] - 
X^2 V[X] Derivative[1][V][X] + 4 X^3 V[X] Derivative[1][V][X] - 
X^3 Derivative[1][V][X]^2 + 2 X^4 Derivative[1][V][X]^2 - 
X^3 V[X] (V^\[Prime]\[Prime])[X] + 
2 X^4 V[X] (V^\[Prime]\[Prime])[X] == 0, V[0] == 0, 
V'[0] == 0}, V, {X, 0, 10^3}]
```

But I have error messages :

> Power: Infinite expression 1/0. encountered.
>
> Power: Infinite expression 1/0.^3 encountered.
>
> Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0. ComplexInfinity ComplexInfinity encountered.
>
> NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at X == 0.`.

How could I go around these problems and solve them ?

Comment: One technique is, instead of starting the integration at the singularity at `X == 0`, to start near it, say at `X = $MachineEpsilon`.

Comment: In your case you'll need a starting value for `X` and `V[X]` so that `Abs[X^4 V[X]]` is somewhat larger than `$MachineEpsilon`....There are probably other ways to go at it, too.

Comment: The only solution with boundary conditions `V[0] == 0, V'[0] == 0` is `V[X] = 0`.